# How to change a piece of text in page based on validation in php script?

Tags: php, forms, text, submit, alter

I have a div tag which forms an area of my site where I wish to allow users to submit their emails to be a part of a mail list. I have the php code which does this, however, there is just some tweaking which I want to do to make it better in terms of usability.

I currently have in html for the area in question

```
    <div id="sideimage1">
    <div id="maillist">
    <div class="sidebartitle">Keep Up To Date</div>
    <div class="sidebartext">Sign up now to receive free newsletters and the best deals direct to your email.</div>
    <form id="maillist" name="maillist" method="post" action="maillistprocess.php" style="padding-top:10px;">

    <div style="text-align:left;"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="40" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:15px; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;" value="name@example.com"/>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top: 15px; text-align: left; margin-left:15px;">
    <input name="submit" type="image" alt="Click To Join Our Mailing List" class="JoinNowbutton" 
    src="../WebImages/JoinNowButton1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='../WebImages/JoinNowButton2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='../WebImages/JoinNowButton1.jpg'"/></div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

I was wondering if anyone knew how that when the user clicks the join button it replaces the 'sibebartext' which something such as 'Congratulations' or 'You have not entered a vlaue' based on the results of the validation in my php script which looks out for an empty box. Until I know how to do this i just have my php direct user back to home page when they have successfully signed up.

I think may need to be done with a jquery but not got too much experience with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so basically change it from a normal form submission to an ajax request?

Comment: im not sure, i was hoping you guys would tell me? apologies as im not experiences in ajax

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery for this. A simple way to submit forms by AJAX instead of a regular request can be done using:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var url = $el.attr('action');

  $.post(url, $el.serialize(), function(data) { 
    if (data=='success') {
      $('.sidebartext').html('congratz');
    } else {
      alert('error: ' + data);
    }
  }).error(function() { alert('something went wrong'); });

  return false;
});
```

And then in php just return 'success' as the complete response when its succesful or an error message when its not

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form#maillist").on("submit", function() {
  var s = $("#email").val();
  if(s=="") {
    $(".sidebartext").text("Enter Some Value");
    return false;
    //easier to return false. Else it could get complicated with more checks and all the nested if statments (considering also checking name/addres/etc
  }

  $.ajax({
    url : "check.php",
    data : s,
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {
      if(data=='Completed')
        $('.sidebartext').html("Congratulations!");
      else
        $('.sidebartext').html("Error! " + data); //allow for more information in the error then just error (perhaps invalid email or email already in use)
    }
  }
});
```

IN PHP CHECK AND ECHO "Congratulations!" for success and ECHO "Error!" for some error and also change check.php to your php script name!

Comment: You check for the emailvalue which is a good thing, but when there is an error you dont `return false`. So even after you set the text to 'enter some value' the ajax is still executed. Also you use `#sidebartext` but in his code `sidebartext` is a class, so it wont match any element. use `.sidebartext`. The data returned from ajax is not a `DOM` object, so $(data).text() will only work if check.php would return something like '.sidebartext' or '<div>text</div>', which seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to check blank values then submit the form if everything is fine:

```
function checkForm(){
        if(document.getElementById('email').value == ''){
            document.getElementById('sidebartext').innerHTML = 'You have not entered a vlaue';
        }else{
            form[0].submit;
        }
    }
```

Make sure `<div class="sidebartext">` has an id of `sidebartext` though.

I'd recommend doing a ajax call to ensure that the email actually got inserted into the database. [Here's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) an example.

Another example of an ajax call:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', '/ajax/script.php?id=' + id, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
    {
       //complete
    }
    else
    {
       //try again
    }
}
```

Comment: hey man he said that he is not good at jquery! so, giving example will not work!

Comment: I have given that div an id as you said and have tried that code however, it will not work. the emails are being sent still despite submitting them with nothing in the box.

Comment: in your email textbox you need to remove the value `value="name@example.com"` needs to be `value=""`